# What proportion of question askers never return to the site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users, unanswered-questions

I feel like there are a ton of questions on SO that consist of a question asked by an OP who appears to never return to the site. Sometimes these questions are low-quality or off-topic and they are closed. Others are relatively articulate and appear solvable (possibly with additional information) but the OP never replies to comments. Here's [a recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678370/rcurl-postform-fetching-incorrect-data) that I found myself stumbling onto today only to realize I asked some questions in comments that weren't answered five days ago. [Here's another similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391368/knitr-with-latex-background-color-with-option-result-asis).

It my mind, it seems this occurs all the time. What do the actual data look like? Is this a common situation?

If it is a common situation, what should we do about it? Can these people be sent email message encouraging them to respond to comments or post their own answer if they found it?

Comment: Send emails?  Why not deliver them gifts so that they would return?

Comment: It is undiscoverable, many users just create a new account.  SO would look *very* different if users had to use their email name.

Comment: Regarding [RCurl postForm fetching incorrect data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23678370/456814), if there isn't enough information to solve the asker's problem, I would vote to close as such, and if you're so inclined, downvote as well. These type of questions that get no activity are eventually cleaned up by the system anyways. Finally, **why bother wasting your time trying to help someone who won't reciprocate your effort?** That user was last seen 10 hours ago, according to his/her profile. I guess they don't care about the question anymore.

Comment: +1 I asked a similar question recently http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255735/should-people-who-show-a-lack-of-engagement-with-their-own-questions-be-penalize (Should people who show a lack of engagement with their own questions be penalized?)

Comment: I noticed the authors of both example posts returned to StackOverflow after this question was asked.

Comment: The **main** purpose of this site is to **provide info for the public at large**, **NOT** to answer the OP's question (that's a side purpose).

Comment: @Hans Some of them have to create new accounts; unregistered accounts expire after six months of inactivity.

Answer (score 6):

> If it is a common situation, what should we do about it?

Nothing.

If their question(s) are good, they'll get good answers and have positive effect overall irrespective whether they come back or not. If they need help, they'll come back; If they care to contribute to the site, they'll come back.

> Can these people be sent email message encouraging them to respond to
>   comments or post their own answer if they found it?

Sending emails may border along spamming (like those websites that send me mails that they "miss" me there because, somehow they have got my email address).

If they are in the business of programming, then SO will be "in their face" for pretty much anything they search in Google. So they don't need to be reminded about its existence or quality.

Answer (score 4):

The original poster asks:

> Can these people be sent email message encouraging them to respond to comments or post their own answer if they found it?

I would like to point out that users are ***already*** able to receive emails when someone leaves them a comment, **as long as they subscribe to email updates in their preferences**:

[image: Preferences screenshot]

I don't remember whether or not this is enabled by default, however.

Comment: This is not enabled by default.