# Should people who show a lack of engagement with their own questions be penalized?

Tags: discussion

I've only been answering questions for the last few months, but I notice that there are a lot of people who ask questions and then tune out.  The simplest indicator of this is that they don't respond to questions in the comments.  Other indicators are that they don't upvote and/or accept answers.

I understand that not every question has an answer that should be upvoted or accepted.  Furthermore not every comment merits a response.  However, whenever I see the little red flag up by my inbox I go to the page and check out the comment/answer.  Then the flag goes away.  I bet that there are a bunch of people who don't visit their own question pages when there is a notification.  Is there a way to penalize these people?

Maybe they lose reputation if they don't re-visit their own question within a given amount of time after some activity on the page.  This could possibly apply only for the first week after the question is asked.  Or maybe they are blocked from asking other questions if they fail to engage with their own question.  These are just a few ideas and I'm sure there are other ways to incentivize better engagement with one's own question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They already are penalized.

Users who post drive-by off-topic, under-specified, unclear or unanswerable drive-by questions are met with downvotes, closed questions and no answers.  If this happens a non-trivial number of times, they get banned from asking any more questions.

If you're capable of asking a question that already includes the necessary information to answer it, and demonstrates an adequate knowledge level of the problem domain, you may not need to stick around to address concerns.  This is rare, however.  In most cases, even with good questions, there's still a need to do some follow up.

Answer (score 3):

I think they get their 'penalty' by default; They don't get good answers, their questions tend to get closed and down voted, and the like. I think the system already builds that in.

But I don't think there should be anything automated here. There are lots of 'legitimate' reasons someone could appear to abandon a question, as far as any computer is going to consider it. Having humans apply the 'penalties' is better here, in my opinion.